# Автоматизация процесса генерации сертификатов ЭП

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, x509certificate, certificate

Появился довольно сложный для меня вопрос.
На сервере создан “Центр Сертификации(Локальный)” Active Directory. Когда у пользователя заканчивается срок действия сертификата ЭП(неквалифицированная электронная подпись), ему нужно обратится к работнику поддержки и запросить выпуск нового. Сотрудник службы заходит на портал центра сертификации Microsoft и генерирует новый сертификат. Поскольку пользователей много, это занимает кучу времени. Так вот мой вопрос в том, можно ли каким-то образом автоматически выдавать сертификаты пользователям, когда срок действия предидущих закончится?